# How to reset json file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to reset a json file to an original state after a button is clicked. Currently, I am modeling with router, and I need help to extend my existing code.

This is a code snippet I wrote on server.js file, the one that I run "nodemon" to start the server.

```
var messages = [{index:0, rating:0}, {index:1, rating:0}]
app.get('/votes', (req, res) =>{
    res.send( messages )
})

app.post('/votes', (req, res) =>{
    votes.push(votes)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

so my **initial** state on file 'votes' (json format) is:

```
[{"index":0,"rating":0}, {"index":1, "rating":0}]
```

After some user actions, I'll add some data to this json file using this code:

```
<body>
// some logic here
    <script>
        $(() => {
            $("#submit").click(()=>{
                var message = [ { index:1, rating: $("#input").val()},
                                { index:2, rating: $("#input2").val()}]
                postMessage(message)
            })
        })
        function postMessage(message) {
            $.post('http://localhost:8080/votes', message)
        }
   </script>
</body>
```

and then I have the following in my json file

```
[{"index":0,"rating":0}, {"index":1, "rating":0}, {"index":1, "rating":1}, {"index":2, "rating":3}]
```

QUESTION: How do I reset the json file (not json variable) into the **initial** state with a button click for a new transaction?
I am just doing prototyping, so a quick and dirty way may work.

Comment: There are two ways I can immediately think of off the top of my head.  1) Store the data in a database and have a default value that you load up on the page every time the page refreshes.  2) You can have a JSON object that exists in a file that you could load up every time you wanted to "reset".

Comment: Where's the JSON file in your code?  I don't see any file.

Comment: just edited my description. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommand build or use some sort of user verification, and for each user have a copy of the initial data just for him. Keep in mind that this data will never garbage collected so you will have to manage deletion by yourself. I used basic IP that is given by express but that is not a good practice.
Use [npm-memorystore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystore) which will give your some memory management.
If you want to identify users you can use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)

```js
var messages = [{
    index: 0,
    rating: 0
}, {
    index: 1,
    rating: 0
}];
var usersMessages = {};

app.get('/votes', (req, res) => {
    var userIp = req.ip;
    usersMessages[userIp] = [].concat(messages);
    res.send(usersMessages[userIp]);
});

app.post('/votes', (req, res) => {
    var userIp = req.ip;
    var userVotes = usersMessages[userIp];
    if (!userVotes)
        usersMessages[userIp] = [].concat(messages);
    usersMessages[userIp].push(req.body.votes);

    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this:

```js
$(() => {
  let message = [];

  $("#submit").click(() => {
    //fill with values
    message = [
      { index: 1, rating: $("#input").val() },
      { index: 2, rating: $("#input2").val() }
    ];

    postMessage(message); //send post
    message = []; //reset array
  });

  function postMessage(message) {
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/votes", message);
  }
});

Hope this helps. =D
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, just remove all of the object from array.

You can do that as follow.

```
var messages = [{"index":0,"rating":0}, {"index":1, "rating":0}, {"index":1, "rating":1}, {"index":2, "rating":3}];
messages.length = 1;
console.log(messages);
```

Another way.

```
var messages = [{"index":0,"rating":0}, {"index":1, "rating":0}, {"index":1, "rating":1}, {"index":2, "rating":3}];  
messages = messages.slice(0,1);
console.log(messages);
```

What above code do is, it will just set array back to it first value.